# How does the conditional operator work with a negation?

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator, not-operator

I'm beginning to learn asynchronous javascript and, while I did understand callbacks and promises, something about the code I was learning got my attention. For example:

```
function funcA(){
    console.log('World')
}

function funcB() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log('Hello')

        const error = false
        !error ? resolve() : reject('Error')
    })
}

funcB()
.then(funcA)
.catch(err => console.log(err))
```

In this case, isn't the **!error** saying *if(error === true)* then resolve it, and *else (error === false)*, reject()?

Or it is simple saying "if there is no error, than resolve"?

Comment: ternary operators are best used as expressions (as argument for functions, assignments, etc..). In this case, a normal `if .. else` would've sufficed.

Comment: This is not an issue with callbacks or promises. As @Tibebes.M says, it is essentially

if (error) { reject() } else { resolve() }

Comment: I wrote the code myself after a lesson about promises, so, in this case, I shouldn't use the ternary operator? I thought I would use it just to save space =) About the code, I think I got confused by the (not) operator, I believed that it would change the value of error, and not just say "if there is no error, then resolve". In my head, the not operator always changed an statement from true to false (or vice-versa).

Comment: @JoãoGabrielOnofre `!error ? resolve() : reject('Error')` is equivalent to `error ? reject('Error') : resolve()`. And yes, an `if` statement would be cleaner, saving space is not a good reason if it makes code less readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example code you provided, the line `!error ? resolve() : reject('Error')` would read "if not error, resolve, else reject with message 'Error'".

It is import to note the not operator(!) at the start of the line. This would be the equivalent to the following:

```
const error = false
if (!error) {
    resolve()
} else {
    reject('Error')
}
```

Comment: PS: I believe the error is just set to a constant false as an example, but you would substitute that with the appropriate error check

Comment: Correct, it can also just be looked at as `if (error === false) {...}`

Comment: I think I got confused by the (not) operator, I believed that it would change the value of error, and not just say "if there is no error, then resolve". In my head, the not operator always changed an statement from true to false (or vice-versa), but now I know what the not operator is telling me, thank you =D

Comment: I see the confusion. the (not) operator does not modify the value on its own. You could still assign the result to a variable if needed. If this answer helped, please mark it as the accepted answer, else you may wait for other answers that may try explain better.

Comment: It helped a lot, thanks! Checked it as the accepted answer ;)